# How to mock Axios with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I have a function in `client/index.js` which is using axios to make a request

```
import axios from "axios";

const createRequest = async (url, method) => {
    const response = await axios({
        url: url,
        method: method
    });
    return response;
};

export default { createRequest };
```

I want to test this function using `jest`, so I created `client/index.test.js`

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";
import axios from "axios";
    
import client from "./";

jest.doMock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()));

describe("Client", () => {

    it("should call axios and return a response", async () => {
        const response = await client.createRequest('http://localhost/', 'GET');

        expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

But when I try to run this, the test is failing and I am getting this error

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

If I use mock instead of doMock, then I am getting this error -

```
ReferenceError: /Users/project/src/client/index.test.js: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: jest
```

`package.json` -

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "author",
    "license": "MIT",
    "private": false,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --experimental-json-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./src/index.js",
        "start:dev": "nodemon --experimental-json-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./src/index.js",
        "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "test:dev": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest --watch",
        "test:coverage": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage",
        "lint": "eslint --fix .",
        "pretty": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.23.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "supertest": "^6.1.3"
    },
    "jest": { "testEnvironment": "node" }
}
```

I am running this in node env and node version is `14.16.0`, jest version is `26.6.3`.
Please help to identify what is wrong in this approach and how to fix it.

Comment: Try using `jest.mock` instead of `jest.doMock`. The latter is not hoisted above `import` statements as per the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options)

Comment: Remove the `@jest/globals` import. Can't see any reason to have it there as `jest` is always in scope when running tests

Comment: @Phil if I remove `@jest/globals` then I am getting this `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582674/jest-mock-of-es6-class-yields-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) for answers

Comment: @Phil I have added package.json, maybe that will help.

Comment: Have you looked into the [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend an entirely different way of approaching this. Rather than trying to mock Axios, which is a relatively complicated API that *you don't own*, test at the network boundary using a tool like [`msw`](https://mswjs.io/). This allows you to freely refactor the implementation *without* needing to change the tests, giving you more confidence it's still working. You could do things like:

- Factor out repeated config to `axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost", ... })`;
- Switch to a different library for the requests (e.g. `node-fetch`).

Also if the Axios API changed your tests would start failing, *telling you your code no longer works*. With a test double, as that would still implement the previous API, you'd have passing but misleading test results.

Here's how that kind of test might look; note that Axios isn't mentioned at all, it's just an implementation detail now and we only care about the *behaviour*:

```js
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

import client from "./";

const body = { hello: "world" };

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get("http://localhost", (_, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(body))
  })
);

describe("Client", () => {
    beforeAll(() => server.listen());

    afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

    afterAll(() => server.close());

    it("should call the API and return a response", async () => {
        const response = await client.createRequest("http://localhost/", "GET");

        expect(response).toMatchObject({ data: body, status: 200 });
    });
});
```

Note I've had to use `.toMatchObject` because you're exposing the whole Axios response object, which contains a lot of properties. This isn't a good API for your client, because now *everything* using the client is consuming the Axios API; this makes you heavily coupled to it, and dilutes the benefits I mentioned above.

I'm not sure how you're planning to use it, but I'd be inclined to hide the details of the transport layer entirely - things like status codes, headers etc. are not likely relevant to the business logic in the consumer. Right now you really just have:

```js
const createRequest = (url, method) => axios({ method, url });
```

at which point your consumers might as well just be using Axios directly.

Comment: Actually, mocking Axios makes perfect sense, since it provides enough abstraction over XHR/Node http via adapters and interceptors and was designed with these concerns in mind. In case complex API is an issue, there's official Moxios library, as well as several independent ones. MSW makes more sense in integration/e2e scenarios that can't or shouldn't be focused on specific implementation. Also, network transport isn't something that a user owns or fully controls either, Nock and MSW for Node do much more black magic than Axios mocking would ever need.

Comment: @EstusFlask that doesn't really address what I said. It's a well architected abstraction, but still not one you own. The network layer is at least an existing seam, if another is needed introducing a facade you _do_ own and replacing _that_ with a test double minimises coupling between your code and tests and the third party interface.

Comment: The problem is that test double operates on API that wasn't designed to be mocked this way, i.e. patches Node `http` lib, likely internal parts of it. I don't remember if this caused problems for me with Nock but I'm sure there are known issues. It's a legit tool if it serves the purpose but I wouldn't think of it as of a superior solution. I don't see much problems with coupling, as long as it's unit or integration test that has access to Axios instances, as required by Axios testing libs. Making every test as tolerable to all possible refactorings as it can be is a bit far-fetched approach.

Comment: If you're just making some get/post requests, mocking out axios isn't that complicated, even if you end up writing a wrapper around it. Using a whole new tool to mock out the entire network seems much more complicated.

Comment: @kdazzle e.g. `{ get: () => ({ json: () => body }) }` isn't _that_ complicated, no. But now your tests are coupled to how you're interacting with a third-party library. If you decide, as I said in the answer, to use `axios.create`, you have to rewrite the test double. If you decide to use `res.text()` and parse the JSON elsewhere, you have to rewrite the test double. If you decide to `fetch`, you have to rewrite the test double. At that point, unless you reimplement Axios, you don't have useful tests describing desired behaviour and facilitating ongoing development, you have change detection.

Answer (score 8):

`jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)` method will NOT automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. This means the `axios` function used in the `createRequest` function will still be the original one.

You need to use `jest.mock()`.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const createRequest = async (url, method) => {
  const response = await axios({
    url: url,
    method: method,
  });
  return response;
};

export default { createRequest };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import client from './';

jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('teresa teng')));

describe('Client', () => {
  it('should call axios and return a response', async () => {
    const response = await client.createRequest('http://localhost/', 'GET');
    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response).toEqual('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67101502/index.test.js (11.503 s)
  Client
    ✓ should call axios and return a response (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.62 s
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, like in your answer I changed to jest.mock() and removed import of `@jest/globals`. Then i get this error - `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Answer (score -2):

If you can, try to restructure your code to use the Dependency Injection pattern.

### Example without DI:

```js
/**
 * Example without dependency injection.
 */
class MyService {
  async doThing() {
    const axios = require("axios");
    return (await axios.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://example.com",
      data: "",
      headers: {},
    })).data
  }
}

const s = new MyService();

s.doThing();
```

### Example with DI:

```js
/**
 * Example with dependency injection.
 */
class MyService {
  /**
   * @param request
   *   An async function that takes method, url, body and headers as arguments and returns a promise that resolves to
   *   the deserialized response body.
   */
  constructor(request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  async doThing() {
    return this.request("GET", "http://example.com", "", {});
  }
}

const s = new MyService(async (method, url, body, headers) => {
  const axios = require("axios");
  return (await axios.request({
    method,
    url,
    data: body,
    headers,
  })).data;
});

s.doThing();
```

This can be improved even further using TypeScript:

```
/**
 * An async function that takes method, url, body and headers as arguments and returns a promise that resolves to
 *   the deserialized response body.
 */
export type RequestFunction = (
    method: "GET" | "POST",
    url: string,
    body: string,
    headers: Record<string, string>
) => Promise<any>;

/**
 * Example with dependency injection.
 */
class MyService {
    public readonly request: RequestFunction;

    constructor(request: RequestFunction) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    async doThing() {
        return this.request("GET", "http://example.com", "", {});
    }
}

const s = new MyService(async (method, url, body, headers) => {
    const axios = require("axios");
    return (await axios.request({
        method,
        url,
        data: body,
        headers,
    })).data;
});

s.doThing();
```

This had many benefits:

- Code is more modular.
- Mocking becomes VERY easy, regardless of your test framework.
- You don't force your favorite request library on your users.

### To test:

```js
describe("MyService", () => {
  it("does a thing", async () => {
    const s = new MyService(async () => ({ foo: "bar" }));
    expect(await s.doThing()).toEqual({ foo: "bar" });
  })
})
```