# How to mock API calls made with Axios?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component called Home.jsx which makes an async call in useEffect with the help of an axios instance. Now while writing tests for Home in Home.test.jsx, I'm facing issues with this API call as the API call requires authorization and the tests are run in the terminal not the browser. If I use `findBy` or `waitFor` then the API call is supposed to fail as there is no authorization happening. I'm using an `axios.create({})` instance and no other questions helped me.

```
//Home.jsx
import services from "../../Services/patientServices";

const Home = () => {
  const [patientSets, setPatientSets] = useState([]);

  const fetchPatientSets = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await services.patientSets();
      console.log('Data => ', result);
      setPatientSets(result.data);
    }
    catch(err) {
      setPatientFetching(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPatientSets();
  }, []);
}
```

```
//Services.js
import apiClient from "./apiClient";

const patientSets = async () => {
  return await apiClient().get(`patient_sets`);
};
```

```
//ApiClient.js
const apiClient = () => {
  const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: window.config.apiUrl,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    },
    responseType: "json"
  });
 return instance;
}
```

```
//Home.test.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '../../setupTests';
import Home from './Home';

describe('Home', () => {
  test('Test refresh button in the table', async () => {
    const { container } = render(<Home />);
    expect(await screen.findBy('async data').toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to mock Axios to unit test `Home`, just `patientSets`. You can also use something like MSW, see the example I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107497/3001761). But as of yet you don't seem to have tried to mock _anything_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Home` component directly depends on the `patientServices` module. In order to make the unit as small as possible, you should mock `patientServices` instead of `axios`.

The larger the unit, the more complex the test.

E.g.

`Home.jsx`:

```
import services from './services/patientServices';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Home = () => {
  const [patientSets, setPatientSets] = useState([]);

  const fetchPatientSets = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await services.patientSets();
      console.log('Data => ', result);
      setPatientSets(result.data);
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPatientSets();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {patientSets.map((p) => {
          return <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`apiClient.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = () => {
  const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: window.config.apiUrl,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    },
    responseType: 'json',
  });
  return instance;
};

export default apiClient;
```

`services/patientServices.js`:

```js
import apiClient from '../apiClient';

const patientSets = async () => {
  return await apiClient().get(`patient_sets`);
};

export default { patientSets };
```

`Home.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { Home } from './Home';
import services from './services/patientServices';

jest.mock('./services/patientServices');

describe('67122477', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mResult = { data: [{ name: 'teresa teng', id: '1' }] };
    services.patientSets.mockResolvedValueOnce(mResult);
    render(<Home />);
    const matched = await screen.findByText(/teresa teng/);
    expect(matched).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67122477/Home.test.jsx (11.771 s)
  67122477
    ✓ should pass (45 ms)

  console.log
    Data =>  { data: [ { name: 'teresa teng', id: '1' } ] }

      at examples/67122477/Home.jsx:10:15

---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |   80.77 |      100 |    62.5 |   82.61 |                   
 67122477            |   85.71 |      100 |   83.33 |   84.21 |                   
  Home.jsx           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  apiClient.js       |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 4-13              
 67122477/services   |      60 |      100 |       0 |      75 |                   
  patientServices.js |      60 |      100 |       0 |      75 | 4                 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.449 s
```