# How to wait for jQuery event handler that executes an async function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I recently had to add some async functions into my code, and it has led to issues in my jest testing.

I had a number of jQuery event handlers that *looked* like this:

```
// production code
jQuery(document).on('change', 'selector', (function () {
    // ...
    function(); // loads a hard-coded bit of JSON or loads from localStorage
    // ...
}));
```

```
// jest code for checking the side effects
/// @Note: 'selector2' below is not the same as 'selector' above, but the event handler 
/// will be called due to the event propagation
$('selector2').trigger('click');
expect($('selector2').prop('checked')).toBe(true); // checkbox should become checked
expect(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))).toBe(true); // localStorage should change
```

that now look like this:

```
// production code
$(document).on('change', 'selector', (async function () {
    // ...
    await functionButNowItsAsync(); // uses fetch() to load the JSON or loads from localStorage
    // ...
}));
```

```
// jest code for checking the side effects
/// @Note: 'selector2' below is not the same as 'selector' above, but the event handler 
/// will be called due to the event propagation
$('selector2').trigger('click');
/* The following no longer pass because the promise is not resolved */
expect($('selector2').prop('checked')).toBe(true); // checkbox should become checked
expect(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))).toBe(true); // localStorage should change
```

My research has brought me to [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname), [this blog post](https://joegornick.com/2019/08/21/how-to-test-and-wait-for-react-async-events/), and [jQuery.triggerHandler](https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

- I don't believe the first is appropriate, because I'm not trying to spy on named functions, these are anonymous function handlers
- The options in the second link look to be useful for cases where the code is returning promises directly
- The third is only useful if I have event handlers for a specific selector that only call a single handler. That is not the case for my code base, as evidenced by 'selector' and 'selector2' earlier. Changing this would require a non-inconsequential amount of work, so I am resistant to doing that without exploring all my other options first.

My first question is, am I understanding the asynchronous concepts correctly, or am I missing something fundamental that would make my task easier?
Secondly, is there a way to 'await' for the async event handler?

Comment: I would approach this by using MSW to provide a response to the fetch (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107497/3001761) and then _waiting_ for the DOM to be updated (e.g. https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/ with DOM Testing Library). Then you don't need to spy on anything or directly trigger jQuery events, which would couple your tests to the _implementation_ not the _behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've been tinkering with your suggestion with respect to using the waitFor() function from the DOM Testing Library. I don't believe I can eliminate the jQuery trigger calls, because the expects are testing the behavior of the event handler as a whole, not just the ```functionButNowItsAsync``` call. I also can't call that function directly, as it's not exposed outside the class it lives in. Wrapping the expects in a waitFor() have gotten me farther though

Comment: You'll still need the trigger event to happen, but you can express it at a higher level with e.g. getByRole (see https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority) and https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/.