# Test Axios get request in React and Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to React testing and was essentially wondering how to mock the behaviour of a successful get request from Axios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need me to provide more info please let me know (I've only posted the relevant code). Alternatively if anyone knows of any useful links to React testing with Axios that would also be appreciated! :)

the test

```
it("Submit button should make a fetch request return a given Github user.", () => {
    render(<FavouriteLanguage />);
    let mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Submit"));
    const searchGithubUsers = mock.onGet(
        `https://api.github.com/users/thatguy560/repos?per_page=100`,
        { language: "JavaScript" }
    );
    expect(searchGithubUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Code

```
import { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import sortKeysByValue from "sort-keys-by-value";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "./css/FavouriteLanguage.css";

class FavouriteLanguage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchedUsername: "",
            programmingLanguagesUsed: "",
        };
    }

    searchGithubUsers = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchedUsername: event.target.value }); 
    };

    getData = () => {
        let username = this.state.searchedUsername;
        axios 
        .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=100`)
        .then((res) => {
            let allProgrammingLanguages = res.data
            .map((data) => data.language)
            .filter((lang) => lang !== null);
            this.setState({ programmingLanguagesUsed: allProgrammingLanguages });
            Swal.fire({
                title: `${
                    username[0].toUpperCase() + username.slice(1).toLowerCase()
                }'s Favourite Programming Language Is:`,
                text: `${this.determineFavouriteLanguage()}`,
                width: 625,
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: `${this.DisplayErrorInfo(error)}`,
                icon: "error",
            });
        });
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <div id="wrap">
                        <h2>Find a user's favourite programming language</h2>
                        <p>Please enter a valid Github username:</p>
                        <form onSubmit={this.getData}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Github username..."
                                onChange={this.searchGithubUsers}
                            />
                        </form>
                        <button
                            id="Submit"
                            type="button"
                            className="btn"
                            onClick={this.getData}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FavouriteLanguage;
```

Error

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"abortRequest": [Function abortRequest], "abortRequestOnce": [Function abortRequestOnce], "networkError": [Function networkError], "networkErrorOnce": [Function networkErrorOnce], "passThrough": [Function passThrough], "reply": [Function reply], "replyOnce": [Function replyOnce], "timeout": [Function timeout], "timeoutOnce": [Function timeoutOnce]}
```

Comment: Have a look at Mock Service Worker. I use that to mock all my api calls in react https://mswjs.io/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock Axios with Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101502/how-to-mock-axios-with-jest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on right track! I'd recommend moving your `MockAdapter` into its own file (for reusability):

**`utils/mockAxios.js`**

```js
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
import axios from "axios";

const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);

export default mockAxios;
```

Then you can import it, add some mocks to it (you can chain axios responses with `replyOnce` and/or `reply` to test both failing/successful API responses, see [chaining is also supported](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#:%7E:text=Chaining%20is%20also%20supported)), and then make assertions against the **result** (in this case, spy on `Swal.fire` and make assertions on how its being called):

**`__tests__/FavouriteLanguage.js`**

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import FavouriteLanguage from "./FavouriteLanguage";
import mockAxios from "./utils/mockAxios";

// spying on Swal.fire, turning into a "spy" mocked function
const mockSpy = jest.spyOn(Swal, "fire"); 

const username = "example";
const API_URL = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=100`;

// chaining axios responses...
mockAxios
  .onGet(API_URL)
  .replyOnce(404) // at first, it fails to fetch
  .onGet(API_URL)
  .reply(200, [{ language: "Javascript" }]); // then it successfully returns an array of objects, where each object refers to the user's projects; in this simple example, I'm just returning a single project

beforeEach(() => {
  mockSpy.mockClear(); // clear any previous calls to this spy mock
});

afterAll(() => {
  mockSpy.mockRestore(); // restore spy mock to original Swal.fire
});

it("fails to make an API request to retrieve a github user and displays a sweet alert error", async () => {
  render(<FavouriteLanguage />);

  // updates input with "example" username
  userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("username"), username);

  // submits the form
  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("submit"));

  // using "waitFor" because submitting the form calls an async request
  // therefore you need to "waitFor" the request to resolve
  await waitFor(() => {
    // expect Swal.fire to be called with an error
    expect(Swal.fire).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      title: "Error: Request failed with status code 404",
      icon: "error",
    });
  });
});

it("makes an API request to retrieve a github user's details and displays a sweet alert with user's favorite language.", async () => {
  render(<FavouriteLanguage />);

  userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("username"), username);

  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("submit"));

  await waitFor(() => {
    // expect Swal.fire to be called with user's favorite language
    expect(Swal.fire).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      text: "Javascript",
      title: "Example's Favourite Programming Language Is:",
      width: 625,
    });
  });
});
```

I tweaked your code a bit to make the above work, but you can retweak it to work with your code:

**`FavouriteLanguage.js`**

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
// import sortKeysByValue from "sort-keys-by-value";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
// import "./css/FavouriteLanguage.css";

class FavouriteLanguage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchedUsername: "",
      programmingLanguagesUsed: "",
    };
  }

  searchGithubUsers = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchedUsername: event.target.value });
  };

  getData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // make sure to call e.preventDefault when submitting a form; otherwise, it'll refresh the page

    const username = this.state.searchedUsername;
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=100`)
      .then((res) => {
        let allProgrammingLanguages = res.data
          .map((data) => data.language)
          .filter((lang) => lang !== null);

        this.setState({ programmingLanguagesUsed: allProgrammingLanguages });

        Swal.fire({
          title: `${
            username[0].toUpperCase() + username.slice(1).toLowerCase()
          }'s Favourite Programming Language Is:`,
          text: `${res.data[0].language}`,
          width: 625,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          title: `${error.toString()}`,
          icon: "error",
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div id="wrap">
            <h2>Find a user's favourite programming language</h2>
            <p>Please enter a valid Github username:</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.getData}>
              <input
                data-testid="username"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Github username..."
                onChange={this.searchGithubUsers}
              />
              <br />
              {/* 
                 Since you're already using a form, 
                 put the button inside of it and use type="submit".
                 Clicking the "submit" button calls "this.getData"!
               */}
              <button data-testid="submit" type="submit" className="btn">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FavouriteLanguage;
```

**Result:**
[image]