# Mocking axios create dynamically with jest

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

I am trying to mock axios with jest. This is what I have currently:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  create: jest.fn(() => function () {
    return {
      data: {
        data: {
          subscription: [
            {
              tag: 'free',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  }),
}));

describe('Subscription store', () => {
  it('fetches subscription data', async () => {
    const subscription = useSubscriptionStore();
    await subscription.fetch();
  });
});
```

This works and I dont get any errors. But I want to make different test cases with different return data properties and I want to pass them dynamically to mock.

```
return {
      data: {
        data: {
          subscription: [
            {
              tag: 'free',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
```

I tryed doing it like this

```
const mockAxios = (data) => {
  jest.doMock('axios', () => ({
    create: jest.fn(() => function () {
      return data;
    }),
  }));
};


describe('Subscription store', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it('fetches subscription data', async () => {
    const data = {
      data: {
        subscription: [
          {
            tag: 'premium',
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    mockAxios(data);
    const subscription = useSubscriptionStore();
    await subscription.fetch();
  });
});
```

And this is my service class where I am mocking axios to make tests work:

```
export default class Http {
 constructor() {
    this.axios = Axios.create();
 }

 sendRequest(method, url, config) {
    const promise = this.axios({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      ...config,
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

But now I get errors like this:

[image]

So I dont know how to make this work would appreciate some help.

Comment: This is a good example of why you don't mock what you don't own - Axios has a relatively complicated API, and you end up reimplementing a lot of it to support even basic refactoring. This couples your code and tests to a third party. Isolate with a simple facade you _can_ easily mock, or use a tool like MSW to mock at the network layer (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107497/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

Updated code is that you are returning the data object directly from the create function, instead of wrapping it in a response object with a data property. This is causing Axios to throw an error with status code 404 because it expects a response object.

like this:

```
const mockAxios = (response) => {
  axios.create = jest.fn(() => axios);
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response);
};

describe('Subscription store', () => {
  it('fetches subscription data', async () => {
    const data = {
      subscription: [
        {
          tag: 'premium',
        },
      ],
    };

    mockAxios({ data });

    const subscription = useSubscriptionStore();
    await subscription.fetch();

    expect(subscription.data).toEqual(data.subscription);
  });

  it('handles error response', async () => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    mockAxios(Promise.reject(error));

    const subscription = useSubscriptionStore();
    await expect(subscription.fetch()).rejects.toEqual(error);
  });
});
```

---

Therefore, you need to add a mock for the get method as well, like this:

```
const mockAxios = (response) => {
  axios.create = jest.fn(() => axios);
  axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(response);
};
```

Comment: Now it throws this  ```TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function```

Comment: "TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function" suggests that the mockResolvedValue method is being called on an undefined value, possibly because the axios.get method is not being mocked properly. Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are trying to mock the create method of the axios module, but not the get method that is being called in your service class. 

You try:


const mockAxios = (response) => {
  axios.create = jest.fn(() => axios);
  axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(response);
};