Vitest not picking up my mocked environment variables when testing axios call
I've got the following function:
import axios from 'axios'

const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_KEY
const apiURL = import.meta.env.VITE_URL

const headers = {
  'key': apiKey,
  'host': apiURL.replace('https://', '')
}

export const getData = async () => {
  return axios.get(apiURL + '/items', { headers: headers })
    .then(response => response)
}

I'm trying to write a test for it like this:
import { getData } from '@/services/api.js'
import axios from 'axios'

vi.mock('axios')

vi.stubEnv('VITE_KEY', 'mockApiKey')
vi.stubEnv('VITE_URL', 'https://mockApiUrl')

const mockHeaders = {
  'x-rapidapi-key': import.meta.env.VITE_KEY,
  'x-rapidapi-host': import.meta.env.VITE_URL.replace('https://', '')
}

test('getData is working', async () => {
  const mockData = [
    { name: 'mockData' }
  ]

  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { data: mockData } })

  const data = await getData()

  expect(data).toEqual(mockData)
  expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(import.meta.env.VITE_URL + '/items', { headers: mockHeaders })
})

But the test is failing because axios.get is using the real environment variables as headers instead of the those mocked in the tests with stubEnv. Why are the test environment variables not being picked up?

Those values are evaluated when the module is imported, which is before you vi.stubEnv. If you moved the header creation and access to import.meta.env inside getData, or imported the module under test after you stubbed the environment, it would work (although using import.meta.env.VITE_URL to assert on that same value is a bit "marking your own homework").

@jonrsharpe how would you suggest making this better? Not asserting the headers?

I don't much like mocking Axios, as discussed in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107497/3001761, but in terms of the assertion I'd extract the values the mock use and access them directly in the test, rather than get them the same way the system under test does: vi.stubEnv('VITE_URL', baseUrl), expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(\${baseUrl}/items`, ...)`.
