# Jest Spy not being called

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, winston

I am trying to run a test using the [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) logger package. I want to spy on the createlogger function and assert that it is being called with the correct argument.

Logger.test.ts

```
import { describe, expect, it, jest, beforeEach, afterEach } from '@jest/globals';
import { LogLevel } from 'api-specifications';
import winston, { format } from 'winston';
import { buildLogger } from './Logger';
import { LoggerConfig } from './Config';

describe('Logger', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(winston, 'createLogger');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should call winston createLogger with format.json when config.json is true', () => {
    const config: LoggerConfig = {
      json: true,
      logLevel: LogLevel.INFO,
    };
    buildLogger(config);

    expect(winston.createLogger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        level: LogLevel.INFO,
        format: format.json(),
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

Logger.ts

```
import { createLogger, format, transports, Logger } from 'winston';
import { LoggerConfig } from './Config';

const logFormatter = format(info => {
  const values = (info[Symbol.for('splat') as any as string] ?? [])
    .filter(f => typeof f === 'object')
    .reduce(
      (acc, curr) => ({
        ...acc,
        ...curr,
      }),
      {},
    );

  const meta = Object.keys(values)
    .map(k => ` - ${k}=${values[k]}`)
    .join('');

  return { ...info, [Symbol.for('message')]: `${info.level}: ${info.message}${meta}` };
});

export const buildLogger = (config: LoggerConfig): Logger => 
  createLogger({
    level: config.logLevel,
    format: config.json ? format.json() : logFormatter(),
    transports: [new transports.Console()],
  });
```

However when i run the test i get the following output

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: ObjectContaining {"format": {"options": {}}, "level": "info"}

Number of calls: 0
```

Im not quite sure what going on.
Im using the following versions of packages:

- "jest": "28.1.0"
- "ts-jest": "28.0.2"

Comment: Add the import statements as well in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ES modules, there are many ways to solve this issue. Honestly, I do not know which one is better (all of them have upsides and downsides), there might even be a well-known solution that I have not found yet, but I doubt it. The reason is that, from what I have read, Jest support for ES modules is still incomplete, as the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#differences-between-esm-and-commonjs) points out:

> Please note that we currently don't support `jest.mock` in a clean way in ESM, but that is something we intend to add proper support for in the future. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025) for updates.

So, all the followings are just workarounds, not real solutions.

---

#### #1 - Always import the `default` object

You can import `winston` in 2 ways:

1. `import * as winston from 'winston'`: this notation returns a `Module` object, containing the `export`ed properties. Among them you can find a `default` property, pointing to `module.exports` of the CommonJS module.
2. `import winston from 'winston'`: this is a syntactic sugar for `import { default as winston } from 'winston'`. Basically, instead of importing the entire module, you just get the `default` property.

You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#commonjs-namespaces).

`createLogger` can be accessed in 2 ways if you use the first import notation:

```
[Module] object
{
    ...
    createLogger: f() { ... }
    default: {
        ...
        createLogger: f() { ... }
    }
}
```

I am not sure mocking a `Module` object is possible, but in your case it is enough to mock `default.createLogger`. This is quite easy:

**Logger.ts**

```
import winston from 'winston'

export const buildLogger = async (config) => {
    return winston.createLogger({
        level: "info"
    });
}
```

(**Logger.test.ts** is the original one.)

Why does this work? Because both **Logger.test.ts** and **Logger.ts** assign to `winston` (a reference to) the `default` object. `jest.spyOn(winston, 'createLogger')` creates a spy on the method `default.createLogger`, because we have imported only the `default` object. Therefore, the mocked implementation gets shared with **Logger.ts** as well.

The downside is that an import statement like `import { createLogger } from 'winston'` cannot work because you are accessing `Module.createLogger` instead of `Module.default.createLogger`.

---

#### #2 - First mock, then import

With ES modules, `import` statements are hoisted: even if the first line of your **Logger.test.ts** was `jest.mock('winston', ...)`, the **Logger** module would be loaded before that line (because of `import { buildLogger } from './Logger';`). This means that, in the current state, **Logger.ts** references the actual implementation of `createLogger`:

1. Jest loads **Logger.test.ts**
2. Node module loader loads all the modules imported with `import ... from ...`
3. **Logger.ts** is executed, preceded by with `import { createLogger } from 'winston'`.
4. Node continues to execute **Logger.test.ts**, Jest creates a spy on `createLogger`, but **Logger.ts** already references the actual implementation of that method.

To avoid the hoisting, a possibility is to use dynamic imports:

**Logger.test.ts**

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
jest.mock('winston', () => {
  return {
    // __esModule: true,
    // default: () => "test",
    createLogger: jest.fn()
  }
});
const winston = await import('winston')

const { buildLogger } = await import('./Logger');

describe('Logger', () => {
  it('should call winston createLogger with format.json when config.json is true', () => {
    const config = {
      json: true,
      logLevel: "info",
    };
    buildLogger(config);

    expect(winston.createLogger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        level: "info"
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

(**Logger.ts** is the original one.)

Now the module is mocked before importing the logger dependency, which will see the mocked version of `winston`. Just a few notes here:

- `__esModule: true` is probably not necessary in your case (or maybe I was not able to correctly mock the ES module without dynamic imports), but in case you have to mock an ES module that you will use in the **current** test file, then you have to use it. (See [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options))
- I had to configure Jest with `transform: {}`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582674/jest-mock-of-es6-class-yields-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)
- The upside is that the implementation code stays unchanged, but the test code becomes more complex to handle and maintain. Besides, there could be some situations where this does not work at all.

---

#### #3, #4...

There is at least another solution out there, but, just looking at the method name, I would not use it: I am talking about `unstable_mockModule`. I have not found official documentation for it, but it is probably not ready for production code.

Manual mocks could be another way to solve this, but I have not tried it.

---

Honestly, I am not fully satisfied with any of these solutions. In this case, I would probably use the first one, at the expense of the implementation code, but I really hope someone finds something better.

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking:

```
jest.mock('winston', () => {
 return {
   createLogger: jest.fn()
 }
});

describe('Logger', () => {
...
```

Comment: didnt work still facing the same issue