# Get original implementation during jest mock

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, fetch

I'm trying to temporarily mock node-fetch in an ESM module while still retraining the original implementation so I can access a real endpoint's value. However, this errors with "Must use import to load ES Module." I recognize jest support for ESM is still pending - is there any way to have this behavior in a combination of current Node, ES6, and Jest?

worker.ts (dependency):

```
export default async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://example2.org");
    return await response.json()
  }
```

main.test.ts:

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";


jest.mock("node-fetch", () => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({ myItem: "abc" }),
    })
})

import doWork from './worker.js';
import mockedFetch from 'node-fetch';

const originalFetch = jest.requireActual('node-fetch') as any;

test("Ensure mock", async () => {
    const result = await doWork();
    expect(result.myItem).toStrictEqual("abc");
    expect(mockedFetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);

    const response = await originalFetch("http://www.example.org");
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);

    const result2 = await doWork();
    expect(result2.myItem).toStrictEqual("abc");
    expect(mockedFetch).toBeCalledTimes(2);
});
```

Comment: *is there any way to have this behavior in a combination of current Node, ES6, and Jest?* I have answered to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370806/jest-spy-not-being-called/72427822#72427822).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, Jest [doesn't support `jest.mock` in ESM](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#differences-between-esm-and-commonjs) module for tests

> Please note that we currently don't support jest.mock in a clean way
> in ESM, but that is something we intend to add proper support for in
> the future. Follow this issue for updates.

This is reasonable because `import` has different semantic than `require`. All imports are hoisted and will be evaluated at module load **before any module code**.

So in your case because you are using `jest.mock` **I assume that your test code are transformed**. In this case, if you want to use non "CommonJS" package, you should transform it too. You can change `transformIgnorePatterns` in jest config to `[]`. It means that all packages from `node_modules` will go through transform. If it's too aggressive, you can pick specific modules which ignore like this `"transformIgnorePatterns": [ "node_modules/(?!(node-fetch))" ]` but don't forget about transitive dependencies. ;)

- Add/change in jest config

```
  "transformIgnorePatterns": []
```

- jest.mock accept module factory which should returns exported code. In your case, you should write it like this.

```
jest.mock("node-fetch", () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({ myItem: "abc" }),
      })
    ),
  };
});
```

If you have error

> The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables

just remove jest from import and use it as global variable or import it inside the module factory function
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567

- Change `const originalFetch = jest.requireActual('node-fetch')` to

```
const originalFetch = jest.requireActual('node-fetch').default;
```